# Cassandra node not joining cluster after reboot

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing

We have configured 3 node cassandra  cluster in RHEL 7.2 version and we are doing cluster testing. When we start cassandra in all 3 nodes they form a cluster and they work fine.

But when we bring one node down using "init 6" or "reboot" command, the rebooted node takes more time to join the cluster, however if we manually kill and start cassandra process the nodes join cluster immediately without any issues.

We have provided all 3 IPs as seed nodes and the cluster name is same for all 3 nodes and their respective IP as listen address.

Please help us in resolving this issue.

Thanks

**Update**
Cassandra - 3.9 version

1. While investigating the issue further we noticed  Node 1 (rebooted
   node) able to send "SYN", "ACK2" messages for both the nodes (Node
   2, Node 3) even though nodetool status displays "Node 2 and 3 as
   "DN"" only in "Node 1"
2. After 10 - 15min we noticed "Connection Timeout"  exception in Node
   2 and 3. being thrown from OutboundTcpConnection.java (line # 311)
   which triggers a state change event to "Node 1" and changes the
   state as "UN".

   if (logger.isTraceEnabled())
   logger.trace("error writing to {}", poolReference.endPoint(), e);

Please let us know what triggers "Connection TimeOut" exception in "Node 2 and 3" and ways to resolve this.

We believe this issue is similar to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9630

Comment: I'm not sure what you're implying but of course a reboot of the whole machine will take longer than simply restarting a process. Could you elaborate?

Comment: We are running reboot command, and it automatically starts "VM" in a clean state

Answer (score 0):

> But when we bring one node down using "init 6" or "reboot" command, the rebooted node takes more time to join the cluster, however if we manually kill and start cassandra process the nodes join cluster immediately without any issues.

Remember that Cassandra writes everything to the commit log to ensure durability in case of some "plug-out-of-the-wall" event.  When that happens, Cassandra reconciles the data stored on-disk with data in the commit log at start-up time.  If there are differences, it could take a while for that reconciliation to complete.

That's why its important to run these commands before stopping Cassandra:

```
nodetool disablegossip
nodetool drain
```

Disabling gossip makes sure that the node you're shutting down won't take any additional requests.  Drain ensures that anything in the commit log is written to disk.  Once those are done, you can stop your node.  Then the node restart should occur *much* faster.

Comment: Thanks, we are trying to test various cluster testing scenarios. One of the scenario is machine gets crashed, and we manually restart that node. If machine gets crashed, we cannot perform above said operations. We dont notice any operations related to commit log, all we see from the logs is Gossiping.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we believe this issue is due to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9630